# Blockdata Problems

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been working on something that uses lots of blockdata commands. It was all going well until I needed to put a enchanted book that works with anvils into the command so that I could get it out of the chest above and be able to use it to enchant something with efficiency v but I don't know how to make it work.
Here is the command so far:

```
/blockdata ~ ~3 ~ {Items:[{id:403,StoredEnchantments:,Count:1,Slot:0}]}
```

When I put in the correct stuff for StoredEnchantments it doesn't appear. What I'm trying to do is make this command into a blockdata command where the enchanted book will appear in the chest instead of my inventory:

```
/give @p minecraft:enchanted_book 1 0 {StoredEnchantments:[{id:32,lvl:5}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the `StoredEnchantments` tag is not directly in the item's root tag, it is in the `tag` tag. Try this:

```
/blockdata ~ ~3 ~ {Items:[{id:403,Count:1,Slot:0,tag:{StoredEnchantments:[{id:32,lvl:5}]}}]}
```